# Why does this if statement not work as expected?

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^(dsm_print|dsm_label)$ ]] && ! [[ "$2" =~ ^(jqm_print|jqm_label)$ ]]
then
echo "wrong parameters"
exit 1
fi

echo "still runs"
```

Here is the run `sh -x ./test.sh dsm_label jqm_labe` but it does not exit and seems to ignore the check for 2nd parameter.
it is supposed to check for both the parameters and then exit

```
+ [[ dsm_label =~ ^(dsm_print|dsm_label)$ ]]
+ echo 'still runs'
still runs
```

Comment: Does it work as expected if you run it with bash instead of sh? What's your operating system? What is `sh` on your system?

Comment: yes, bash also gives the same error. $1 should be dsm_print or dsm_label. $2 should be jqm_print or jqm_label and it should check both

Comment: What error? What are you expecting this to do? Your test will only fail if both `$1` and `$2` are wrong. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Your test will only fail if both $1 and $2 are wrong. Is that what you really want? yes

Comment: Wait, what? Then it works as expected. Are you sure you don't want it to fail if _either_ is wrong and only want it to fail when _both_ are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check both parameters, you want `||` not `&&`. As it stands, your script will only fail if you give both wrong:

```
$  foo.sh dsm_print wrong
still runs
$  foo.sh wrong jqm_label
still runs
$  foo.sh wrong wrong
wrong parameters
```

That's because `if ! [[ condition1 ]] && ! [[ condition2 ]]` will only be true if both conditions are false. What you want is `||` so it will fail if either of them is false:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^(dsm_print|dsm_label)$ ]] || ! [[ "$2" =~ ^(jqm_print|jqm_label)$ ]]
then
echo "wrong parameters"
exit 1
fi

echo "still runs"
```

This works as expected:

```
$  foo.sh dsm_print wrong
wrong parameters
$  foo.sh wrong jqm_label
wrong parameters
$  foo.sh wrong wrong
wrong parameters
```

Comment: Boolean logic rules ([De Morgan's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)): `!A or !B` == `!(A and B)`